# Angular material table mat row hover change preset background color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a angular material table that have a preset background color on column name

```
.mat-column-name {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

but when I try to change the background color when hover, the column name it wont change the background color

```
.mat-row:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How to force it change? I try put !important also not working
This is demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-u5rty5?file=app/table-basic-example.css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another more specific CSS rule so that the `name` column will also have red background whenever the row is hovered. Try this:

```css
.mat-row:hover,
.mat-row:hover .mat-column-name {
  background-color: red;
}
```